# How can I get a timestamp or a data using datediff function?

Tags: sql, datediff

I am reading some sql code from somebody where DATEDIFF function should return a timestamp. Here is the code:

```
DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE())
```

I do not see any sql syntax like this anywhere. Can anyone explain how this code should return date or timestamp?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388759/11683)

Comment: DATEDIFF is a built-in function provided by the dbms.  It is not part of standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You use DATEDIFF() function to get the difference between two dates, and it returns integer value. Looking at what you are trying to do, it seems you want to add 6 weeks to the current date. In such cases you should use DATEADD() function instead.

Below are some some examples:

```
SELECT DATEADD(ww, 6, GETDATE()),
       DATEDIFF(ww,'6/1/2022', getdate())
```